# AVD Manager - "No system images installed for this target." on API level 23

Tags: android, android-studio, google-api, android-emulator, android-virtual-device

i need to test **Google Maps Android SDK v2**, so I downloaded fallowing SDKs:

[image]

Unfortunatly AVD is throwing message, that no images are installed. I tried to to move content of *system-images* according to many similar threads and it did't help.

My *system-images* structure:

[image]

**EDIT:**
I reinstalled Mac and installed Android Studio (*AS*) and I found, that if I download Google API *System Image* with *AS* AVD, Standalone AVD found it broken. Same with Google API:

[image]

**EDIT2:**
reported on code.google.com [LINK](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=214557)

I would really appreciate if someone found solution.

Comment: Same problem here, with Ubuntu 14.04

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After week I finally found a solution. Now I'm using AVD in Android Studio instead of Standalone AVD and it's working like a charm.

**Broken Standalone AVD:**

- usually located there: `~/Library/Android/sdk/tools/android avd`
- [thread][https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=214557] I created on code.google.com
- if you download **system images / SDKs** with Android Studio AVD -> Standalone AVD found it **broken**

[image]

**Working Android Studio AVD:**

- command line access no longer supported - use tool in Android Studio *Tools -> Android -> AVD*
- if you previously downloaded **system images / SDKs** from Standalone AVD, you should delete them and download them again via Android Studio AVD

[image]